# Column alignment in xtable output

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I'm using `xtable` to manage `R` output in `Sweave`. See code below:

```
CC <- data.frame(
    y = c(449, 413, 326, 409, 358, 291, 341, 278, 312)/12,
    P = ordered(gl(3, 3)), N = ordered(gl(3, 1, 9))
)
CC.aov <- aov(y ~ N * P, data = CC , weights = rep(12, 9))
Summary <- summary(CC.aov, split = list(N = list(L = 1, Q = 2),
                                        P = list(L = 1, Q = 2)))
Summary

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
N            2 1016.7   508.3
  N: L       1 1012.5  1012.5
  N: Q       1    4.2     4.2
P            2  917.4   458.7
  P: L       1  917.3   917.3
  P: Q       1    0.0     0.0
N:P          4  399.3    99.8
  N:P: L.L   1  184.1   184.1
  N:P: Q.L   1  152.1   152.1
  N:P: L.Q   1   49.0    49.0
  N:P: Q.Q   1   14.1    14.1
```

I like to indent the first column as shown in the output above. But when I use `xtable(Summary)` the first column is aligned left. I know how to align left, right or center but could not figure out how to get the output as indented in the first.

Comment: This will probably require a more in depth LaTeX solution, maybe like what's described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/change-alignment-for-individual-table-rows), which _might_ be doable by hacking the `sanitize.text.function` argument. The other option is the more flexible LaTeX commands in **Hmisc** package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example shows how to customize the table combining the use of the `sanitize` argument in xtable and the function `\hskip` in latex.

The code would be:

```
named = rownames(Summary[[1]])
tags= gsub("  "," ",named)
rownames(Summary[[1]])= c(ifelse(nchar(tags)<8,tags,paste("\\hskip .5cm",tags,sep=' ')))
print(xtable(Summary[[1]]), type="latex", sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

EDIT: Following Dwin's suggestion of using

```
grepl("^ ", rownames(Summary[[1]])
```

That provides a more general solution. The code would change to:

```
named = rownames(Summary[[1]])
tags= grepl("^ ", rownames(Summary[[1]]))
rownames(Summary[[1]])= c(ifelse(tags==F,named,paste("\\hskip .5cm",named,sep=' ')))
print(xtable(Summary[[1]]), type="latex", sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Excellent answer. This is what I was looking for. Please append the snap of output for others too. Thanks again.

Comment: @DWin I didn't get the error. However your grepl("^ ", rownames(Summary[[1]]) is a huge improvement to my code. I will update my answer using it. Thanks!!!

Comment: I deleted my comment about the error. Too much editing on my part. Glad you found value in the grepl() strategy.

Comment: Now it is more general. Awesome solution. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce these results. Sanitize text function only seems to work when values are encapsulated in `$`. For all other text, the usual formatting is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the output of xtable to add another column and put empty column dividers in from of the onew you want to indent: (and assuming appropriate document header and footer.)

```
\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
  \hline
& fac & Df & Sum Sq & Mean Sq \\ 
  \hline
N   &        & 2 & 1016.67 & 508.33 \\ 
 &  N: L      & 1 & 1012.50 & 1012.50 \\ 
 & N: Q      & 1 & 4.17 & 4.17 \\ 
P  &        & 2 & 917.39 & 458.69 \\ 
 &  P: L      & 1 & 917.35 & 917.35 \\ 
 &  P: Q      & 1 & 0.04 & 0.04 \\ 
N:P   &      & 4 & 399.28 & 99.82 \\ 
 & N:P: L.L  & 1 & 184.08 & 184.08 \\ 
 &N:P: Q.L  & 1 & 152.11 & 152.11 \\ 
 &N:P: L.Q  & 1 & 49.00 & 49.00 \\ 
 &N:P: Q.Q  & 1 & 14.08 & 14.08 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Nice workable idea. Can you provide R code to get it? Thanks

Comment: I just copied the console output of xtable(Summary[[1]]) and edited it in TeXShop.